# Sparkle Framework, Delegate methods are not getting called under Lion

Tags: macos, sparkle

I am trying to add [Sparkle framework](http://sparkle-project.org/) to my Application for automatic updates.

I did everything as prescribed in the documentation. But the update was not happening. I tried to find out more by putting some `NSLog` statements. What I found this was is quite scary. Most of the delegates does not work.

My application does not have much interface. So I called checkForUpdates directly in the code.

Did anyone faced the same problem? Can anyone help me to get out of this issue?

I'm using Xcode 4.1 under Mac OS X 10.7 Lion.

Comment: Make sure you retain the delegate object or it'll get released, and nothing will be called.